# Printing multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have written a sudoku puzzle code that currently generates a valid sudoku board and then per-mutates each row within each band based on a random numbers 1-9 and then it will swap each row accordingly, however.

```
 for(q=0;q<9;q++){
    for(j=0;j<9;j++){
        printf("%2d",array[q][swap[j]-1]);
    }
        printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What specifically is causing a problem?  Your code would be easier to understand if you broke it into smaller functions, and identified what exactly each one was supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry, its kind of a rough code, but the problem is that i need for my code to instead of swapping rows with rows, to swap columns with columns.

Comment: Just indexing `[permutation[j] - 1]` where the original has `[j]` does the trick. The order in which you print out the permutation is always the same: Outer loop for rows, inner loop for columns. (You `while ( q < 9)` loop is a bit mesleading. Why not use a `for` loop over `i` here?) Also, please include `<stdlib.h>` and `<time.h>`; they are needed for your randomisation code.

Comment: i switched the permutations are u noted but i am still having difficult printing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is not going to work:

```
while(q<9){
    for(q=0;q<9;q++){
```

Once the inner loop finishes, `q` is `9`, so the outer loop will finish immediately. You should use two different loop counters. I think you just meant to have

```
for(j=0;j<9;j++){
    for(q=0;q<9;q++){
```

and not have `g++`,`j++` in the loop.

Comment: I changed the loop based on your comment, and now it prints the correct numbers for the column, but rather printing it from top to bottom it prints the correct numbers for the column from left to right instead like a row.

Comment: Sorry, i just swapped the j and q for loop and now it prints it correctly. Thank you